# Element type must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">", or "/>"

Tags: xml, character-encoding, netsuite

I am developing an integration with Netsuite's XML API, and I occasionally get the error

`Element type \"msmith\" must be followed by either attribute specifications, \">\" or \"/>\"`
when the request has an email address in it (e.g. msmith@gmail.com).

I assume this is because the `@` symbol needs to be encoded, as I have had a similar issue with ampersands and had to encode them as `&amp;`, but as far as I can tell from my searches, the `@` symbol is not a special character in XML.  Is there a way I can encode or format email addresses such that they will be accepted by Netsuite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message isn't complaining about `@`; it's complaining about `<`.

(In XML `<` must be escaped as `&lt;` unless it is beginning a element tag.)

You likely passed `<msmith@gmail.com>` where you should have passed `msmith@gmail.com`.

See also [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085) .

Answer (score 0):

Almost all free values that you try to include in an xml document should be escaped.

If you are using freemarker it will often do that for you depending on the field type and the output format.

If you are building the xml yourself you can create a text node from the value which will escape any reserved characters `document.createTextNode('some text with reserved chars')`
or if you are concatenating strings Netsuite has functions for this:

SS1

```
'<div>'+ nlapiEscapeXML('some text with reserved chars') +'</div>'
```

SS2 using `N/xml`

```
'<div>'+ xml.escape({xmlText:'some text with reserved chars'}) +'</div>'
```